# How can I disable the HTML view in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

So I'm building a website with Drupal as its backend and an Angular frontend. I'm creating all kinds of content-types in Drupal and then I'm exposing those the content through a JSON view (or in other words a RESTful API). However, Drupal also still exposes an HTML view for all content. I wish to disable that, because it is of no use to me and I don't want it to be accidentally found and maybe even indexed.

Is there an easy way to disable the HTML view for all content?

Answer (score 0):

hook_entity_view and from there block access or change render could be one solution

Answer (score 0):

Have your webserver deny based on the content type sent. I believe nginx has `$sent_http_content_type` for this purpose.

Alternatively, write an event subscriber subscribing to `KernelEvents::RESPONSE` and if the response is not a `ResourceResponseInterface` then throw an `AccessDeniedHttpException`.